# importing connect function from 'react-redux'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a short legacy code question about importing connect tag from `react-redux` module. I have seen in a repo it is imported as `import connect from 'react-redux/es/connect/connect'` not as `import { connect } from 'react-redux'`

Do you know why the former developer imported it like that? Everything is working fine but I would like to find out if there is an advantage importing it like that.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same, is just that before we could not use `{ }` to import like `import { connect } from 'react-redux'` so the options were importing all the library or finding a specific file in the folders with an export so you can `import connect from 'react-redux/es/connect/connect'`

Edit: I just realised that curly braces for declaring variables were introduced at the same time that `import`, so I don't know why anyone would do that, but of course still works.

Answer (score 0):

`connect` is not the default export. Use as below.
`import { connect } from "react-redux";`

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/9on71rvnyo?file=/src/components/AddTodo.js:27-65)

Comment: I know how it is usually imported. I am asking rather a why question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it's because they didn't know exactly what they were doing, or they had some intellisense suggest it and just left it without making it more conventional.